# How to increase time values + and - one second in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to get the values for times in List which is the increment of 1 and decrement of 1 .For example if i have time 14:09 then i need to add values in list like 14.08, 14.09,14.10..

Currently I'm getting time from

```
        var bettime1 = ScenarioContext.Current["betplacedtime"];
```

now i want to create list which can have all 3 values as above.

Comment: Try `DateTime.AddSeconds` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DateTimeAddSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) would work. If all you need is 3 time values in a list, then

```
var theList = new[]{-1,0,1}.Select(x=>betttime1.AddSeconds(x)).ToList()
```

Comment: I'm getting error like Error CS1061 'string' does not contain a definition for 'AddSeconds' and no extension method 'AddSeconds' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Which means bettime1 must be [parsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) to DateTime first

Comment: Yes I'm doing it like and still same .
       bettime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(bettime);

Comment: Not sure about your language background, but in C# var is static type, so you need to store the converted date time to another variable (or just directly convert before storing to bettime1)